# Rewarding people for giving amazing answers? (beyond upvoting)

Tags: discussion, answers

Today, I was exploring the featured section of SO and I happened upon this question:

[Demystifying sharedctypes performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853543/demystifying-sharedctypes-performance)

They question itself was fascinating, but look at the answer! Its like a mile long! I read it all and I think I learned a thousand things just reading it. It was amazingly written, sparked a nice discussion, and just all in all is probably one of the best answers I  have EVER seen.

I upvoted it, but I felt like that wasn't enough. Is there a way to...reward an answer we find spectacular? Like a "featured answers" list somewhere? Because if there was, I really think this one should be on it.

Just to be clear, I am asking if there is a way. If there isn't, I am unsure if it is worth having one, but...what do you guys think?

Thanks!

Comment: There is SO newsletter which contains good answers and questions. Other than that,  upvote is the way to reward for good answer/question. It helps the receiver gain further privileges tied to rep as well. You can share the answer on social media to attract other people, with more views, the answerer/questioner is more likely to get more badges and more rep

Comment: @NSNoob thanks very much! Guess I know what I'm subscribing to. XD Hey can you please put your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Another option is if it's that brilliant (it must be to you to warrant raising a meta post about it) is to place a bounty on it with the reason of "award an existing answer" - that'll also draw more attention to it and you can reward the answer of your choice the bounty amount as a "thank you" to the answerer.

Comment: @JonClements this question is not my own--but its funny you should bring that up XD the question actually had a +100 rep bounty on it. So I guess that it in itself is a great reward. :D

Comment: @silentphoenix yup - but it doesn't need to be your question to place a bounty on it - you can do so on others' questions. I was just pointing out that when the bounty expires - you could even add another one explicitly to reward that answer.

Comment: @JonClements oh I did not know you could put bounties on other people's questions! Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Stack Overflow newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) which contains good answers and questions. Other than that, upvote is the way to reward for good answer/question. It helps the receiver gain further [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) tied to reputation points as well. If you still think that's not enough, You can share the answer on social media to attract other people. With more views, the answerer/questioner is more likely to get more badges and more reputation points. The Question you shared has a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) as well and that answer is very likely to win it.

And as Jon Clements Pointed out, "*Another option ,if it's that brilliant, is to place a bounty on it with the reason of "award an existing answer" - that'll also draw more attention to it and you can reward the answer of your choice the bounty amount as a "thank you" to the answerer.*"

Comment: Quick question that I just thought of: if it is really spectacular, is it appropriate then at least to comment like "Good answer!" or something of the kind?

Comment: Nice. Thanks very much!! :D

Comment: @silentphoenix that kind of comment is actually discouraged. [Comments are not recommended for ... compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (from the help center)